# Jenkins java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among steps

Tags: email, jenkins

I'm trying to implement a stage on Jenkins to send email when a failure is produced on Jenkins. I made something similar to the Jenkins documention:

```groovy
    #!/usr/bin/env groovy
    
    node {
    
    stage ('Send Email') {
            
            echo 'Send Email'
            
                post {
                    failure {
                        mail to: 'aa@bb.cc',
                             subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
                             body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
                    }
                }
                        
            }
    
    }
```

But I always get this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among
> steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir,
> dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext,
> emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext,
> git, input, isUnix, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone,
> node, parallel, powershell, properties, publishHTML, pwd, readFile,
> readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step,
> svn, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstash,
> validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials,
> withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv,
> wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant,
> antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken,
> architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix,
> batchFile, booleanParam, branch, buildButton, buildDiscarder,
> caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changelog, changeset,
> choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, cloud, command, credentials,
> cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, docker,
> dockerCert, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars,
> environment, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint,
> frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git,
> github, githubPush, gradle, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter,
> hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal,
> installSource, jacoco, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp,
> jobName, junit, label, lastDuration, lastFailure,
> lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM,
> list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything,
> masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos,
> mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting,
> nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus,
> parameters, password, pattern, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers,
> plainText, plugin, pollSCM, projectNamingStrategy, proxy,
> queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, remotingCLI, run, runParam,
> schedule, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout,
> skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter,
> sourceWildcardFilter, sshUserPrivateKey, stackTrace, standard, status,
> string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace,
> toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, usernameColonPassword,
> usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withAnt, zfs, zip] or globals
> [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]

I saw some others post, but the suggestion made did not work for me

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was having the same problem here. Lots of examples for declarative... none for scripted. It almost leads you to believe that there is no solution, but that wouldn't make sense.

This worked for me (it works without the try/finally -- or catch if you want).

```
node {
    //some var declarations... or whatever

    try {
        //do some stuff, run your tests, etc.            
    } finally {
        junit 'build/test-results/test/*.xml'
    }
}
```

*EDIT: take a look at [their documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/)... accidentally I've done exactly what they recommend. Just click on the "Toggle Scripted Pipeline (Advanced)" link and you'll see it.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: Still working - thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Problem you are having is that you node is not added to declarative pipeline, you can't use post on node. You need to wrap your node with declarative pipeline.

Here is example code

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Send Email') {
            steps {
            node ('master'){
                echo 'Send Email'
            }
        }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            echo 'I will always say Hello!'
        }
        aborted {
            echo 'I was aborted'
        }
        failure {
            mail to: 'aa@bb.cc',
            subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
            body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet worked for me in a scripted pipeline. I have added a new stage to my existing ones.

```
stage ('Send Email') {
        echo "Mail Stage";

         mail to: "email@domainxxx.com",
         cc: 'manager@domainxxx.com', charset: 'UTF-8', 
         from: 'noreply@domainxxx.com', mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: '', 
         bcc: '',
         subject: "CI: Project name -> ${env.JOB_NAME}",
         body: "<b>Example</b><br>Project: ${env.JOB_NAME} <br>Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} <br> URL de build: ${env.BUILD_URL}";
    }
```