# My jenkinsfile does not compile anymore when trying to add a post build action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

My jenkinsfile does not compile anymore when trying to add a POST action. This last one should be displayed to the jenkins console output at the end of build.

Part I is about my jenkinsfile code for which builds are done well.

Part II is the patch added to part I for which any builds fail.

I want to integrate part I and part II to get the expected output described hereafter but integration fails whatever how insertion is made.
I have tried a lot of thing and i'm stucked now, so any help will be appreciate.

// Part I : my base code

```
    node {
    def mvnHome
    stage('Preparation') { 
        git 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-   tests.git'
      // Get the Maven tool.
      // ** NOTE: This 'M3' Maven tool must be configured
      // **       in the global configuration.           
      mvnHome = tool 'M3'
   }
    stage('Build') {
      // Run the maven build
      if (isUnix()) {
         sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package"
      } else {
         bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package/)
      }
   }
   stage('Results') {
      junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      archiveArtifacts 'target/*.jar'
   }
 }
```

//  Part II : code to add to the previous code

```
post {
    always {
        echo 'I have finished and deleting workspace'
        // deleteDir() 
    }
    success {
        echo 'Job succeeeded!
    }
    unstable {
        echo 'I am unstable :/'
    }
    failure {
        echo 'I failed :('
    }
    changed {
        echo 'Things were different before...'
    }
}
```

output expected in the console output : 'Job succeeeded! or I am unstable :/ or 'I failed :(' ... depending on the jenkins build status and always clean the workspace before each new build

Actual result is the error message from the console output :
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir ......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563872/jenkins-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-such-dsl-method-post-found-among-steps)

Comment: show us all entire jenkinsfile plz

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up scripted and declarative pipeline syntax. `post` is part of declarative, but you use the scripted variant (no `pipeline`, but `node` steps).

You have to use `try`/`catch`.

See [the documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#compare).